# How can I modify this query to add total count of 'Questions' per survey, total correct and percentage correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

The query below gives me all the answered questions per survey (question), the user's answers and correct answers.

I will like to modify it to add total # of answered questions per a particular survey, total correct Answers (correctAnswer) and percentabe of correct Answers?

```
select sq.question,
       sc.choice,
       sq.CorrectAnswer,
       sa.score from Survey s
 INNER JOIN SurveyQuestions sq ON s.surveyId = sq.SurveyId 
 INNER JOIN SurveyChoices sc ON sq.questionId=sc.questionId
 INNER JOIN SurveyAnswers sa ON sc.choiceId = sa.choiceId
 INNER JOIN tblLogin tl ON sa.username = tl.username
 WHERE tl.username = 'JohnSmith' and sq.surveyId = 12
 ORDER BY sq.questionId
```

`

```
Survey table:
    [SurveyID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL

SurveyQuestions table
    [QuestionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SurveyID] [int] NULL,
    [Question] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [AnswerType] [char](1) NULL,
    [CorrectAnswer] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [QuestionOrder] [int] NULL
SurveyChoices table
    [ChoiceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Choice] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL


SurveyAnswers table
    [AnswerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChoiceID] [int] NULL,
    [ChoiceText] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NULL
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Table structures would probably be helpful.

Comment: sq.CorrectAnswer is a value stored in your table? Not calculated? For me should born a new child table os SurveyQuestions where you store the answer (with a flag about its correctness)

Comment: @Gratzy and Joe, sorry. I have added the tables and their fields above.

Also, some of the questions are multiple choice. So, some might get some but not all the mutliple choices correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm reading your question right, your current query returns a row per question, but you want to include survey data with this query? So for every question, you also have the number of answers and correct answers for that question's survey?

If that is correct, then you can do this using 
[OVER - PARTITION BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

```
select sq.question,
       sc.choice,
       sq.CorrectAnswer,
       sa.score,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sq.SurveyId) AS TotalAnswers,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN sq.CorrectAnswer = 'RIGHT ANSWER' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY sq.SurveyId) AS CorrectAnswers
 FROM Survey s
 INNER JOIN SurveyQuestions sq ON s.surveyId = sq.SurveyId 
 INNER JOIN SurveyChoices sc ON sq.questionId=sc.questionId
 INNER JOIN SurveyAnswers sa ON sc.choiceId = sa.choiceId
 INNER JOIN tblLogin tl ON sa.username = tl.username
 WHERE tl.username = 'JohnSmith' and sq.surveyId = 12
 ORDER BY sq.questionId
```

Some changes to come from the specifics of how you grab when an answer is correct (that I'm not obviously seeing from your table layout at the moment), etc.

Comment: when the question is submitted, correctAnser is saved in SurveyQuestions table as you can see from the structures I posted. I am getting the following error from your query: `Incorrect syntax near '*'.` on line 6. 

TEC Carlson, I got same result as yours, number 1 for each row. I want all questions added to get total.

Comment: Score was present in your original query, which I copied as a starting point.

Comment: Yes, @Sethcran, that was my fault. I was using sub-query and then used score as an alias but when I removed the sub-query, I forgot to fix that.

In any case, were you able to fix the error I posted?

Comment: Update: I ran your most updated code. The error is gone but it isn't given the correct answer. It shows the total Answers correctly but Total Correct Answers is always 0.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Modify the sq.CorrectAnswer = 'RIGHT ANSWER' condition to return true when a specific question is correct.

Comment: but what is RIGHT ANSWER?

Where did that come from and how does that help to determine correct answer?

Comment: I don't know what it is. It's a placeholder for your logic, because as it stands right now, I don't understand how you get this from your table structure. Your answers table has a ChoiceID and a ChoiceText, but I do not see an immediately obvious way to get whether or not the answer was correct from those columns.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 select 
   Count(sq.surveyId) as 'total # of answered questions per survey'
   sq.question,
   sc.choice,
   sq.CorrectAnswer,
   sa.score from Survey s
 INNER JOIN SurveyQuestions sq ON s.surveyId = sq.SurveyId 
 INNER JOIN SurveyChoices sc ON sq.questionId=sc.questionId
 INNER JOIN SurveyAnswers sa ON sc.choiceId = sa.choiceId
 INNER JOIN tblLogin tl ON sa.username = tl.username
 WHERE tl.username = 'JohnSmith' and sq.surveyId = 12
 Group sq.question,
   sc.choice,
   sq.CorrectAnswer,
   sa.score
 ORDER BY sq.questionId
```